# Joins in mongodb using aggregate $lookup

Tags: mongodb

need help here.

I have two collections, the first collection isn't so big with pretty small documents.

The second has much more items (thousands, could be much more) with medium size documents.

There's a property in the first document that matches a property in the second document.

The relation here is that items in the first collection have many other items in the second collection that are referencing it.

Say for example i have the first collection representing persons and the second one representing credit card transactions. A person may have many transactions.
PersonId is the id of the persons collection and every transaction document in the transactions collection.

I want to write a query to count how many trasactions each person has.

I've seen that it is recommended to use aggregate and lookup.
But when i try that i get a message that the document size exceeds limit.

I'm guessing that this is because it aggregate a person with all its transaction into one document... not sure, its the first time ever i'm experiencing with mongodb.

What would be the best approach to achieve that? Is the aggregate method the right choice?

Thanx!
Gili

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple grouping to get transactions count for each person

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  { $group: {_id: "$personId", count: {$sum:1}}}
])
```

Output will contain person ids and count of transactions for that person. You can match people and transactions stats in memory. You can also use lookup to return transactions stats with some person data. But keep in mind - you will not retrieve entry for people without transactions:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  { $group: {_id: "$personId", count: {$sum:1}}},
  { $lookup:
      {
        from: "people",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "person"
      }
  },
  {$unwind: "$person"},
  {$project:{name:"$person.name", count:"$count"}}
])
```